# Merging objects to reduce size in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

I've downloaded **Inkscape** in order to try to fix this fairly simple problem.

I have a .svg file that is too big for the intended purpose. I've already taken the steps I could in order to reduce it in size, but still need to cut another 30% off it. What I intend to do, is simplify the image.

This is a part of the vector file:

[image]

From what I can tell, it consists of 3 objects. (The white, light blue and blue parts).
I want to reduce the detail, and just have the entire object be white, as a single object. I've selected the 3 objects and combined them.

The result is the 3 objects are now glued together, but I can see it still consists of the same number of vectors, defeating the purpose of trying to reduce the file size.

Is there anyway, I can get the program to merge the objects together in such a way, that it becomes a new simpler object, consisting of fewer vectors?

If not, what would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Hi there Scherling, can you show us what you are seeing inside the program or share the svg code?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I think you've misunderstood the question. I'm not looking for help for a specific file, I'm asking about general functionality of the software. I want to know how x number of objects can be combined into a single object with the most efficient number of vectors possible

Comment: You are specifically asking about this letter E but want a strategy handed to you for a whole file. I'd reword your question to better reflect that. 
You also say you've taken "the steps I could in order to reduce it in size". what steps? Can you expand and elaborate?

Comment: Hi @Scherling. Welcome to GDSE. Do you know how the E is actually constructed?  Is it solid objects with a clipping mask?  I can't really  tell what it is from the image you posted. Can you at least share the SVG so we can investigate it?  Consider uploading to svgshare(dot)com - it doesn't have to be the whole artwork, the E with the waves should be enough. Perhaps also include the version you have modified. Thanks.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor a lot of software tools for working with .SVG files adds extra fluff to the files when saving them. It is possible to clean up the file without loss of quality of the actual image.

Comment: Have you tried to [simplify](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html) the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Inkscape select your objects and try

> Menu > Path > Union

Now you should suddenly have only one object and some less points (smaller file). The colour will jump to one of the colours from the selected objects. And you can easily turn the new object white.

If this does not work, then your "objects" are not paths but something more complex. Try

> Menu > Path > Object to Path

with each item and then try again my initial idea.

Note: We can help you much better here, if you give more detail.

Comment: I converted to path, and used the Union function. While at first, it didn't actually remove all the points, this made it easy to remove excess points inside the object, thus achieving the goal

Answer (score 0):

Use a site like [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/).

It has a simple interface and it will reduce most SVGs by 20%+

[image]

This is a sample SVG that is 24.97% smaller with all the options checked.

Comparing the original and the SVGOMG versions you can see the drastic drop in overall points.

[image]

Every SVG will have such a drastic drop in size or complexity but SVGOMG should help immensely to hit your target sizes.

Comment: @Scherling If it fills your needs please mark this as the accepted answer.